# Is it possible to create outPorts to both top and bottom part of joint js element?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jointjs

I have created elements with outPorts in bottom or top part. My requirement is to create an element which have outPorts in top and bottom parts.
Is it possible?

Comment: I could able to add port only on one side. Don't know how to add to more than one position...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JointJS v1.0 there are many pre-defined port layouts. Including Bottom/top positions. It comes also with a new port API where ports can be added to any shape easily (`joint.shapes.devs.Model` is not needed anymore).

demo: 
http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.0/demo/layout/Port/port.html

doc:
http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.0/joint.html#layout.Port